# systematically changing filenames in a directory w/ Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io, naming

I'd like to grab all the files in a particular directory, and then apply a gsub(/abc/,'z') to all the filenames and essentially resave the files under the new filenames, how do I do that?

I've been looking at File but I don't seem to have any of the parameters that it requires, aka the filename, etc.

M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File.rename(from, to)](http://apidock.com/ruby/File/rename/class) along with [Dir.entries](http://apidock.com/ruby/Dir/entries/class) (or [Dir.foreach](http://apidock.com/ruby/Dir/foreach/class))?

Answer (score 2):

Dave's answer is right on. Here's an example:

```
Dir.glob("*.rb").each do |fname|
  File.rename(fname, fname.gsub(/\.rb/,".rbb"))
end
```

`Dir.glob` allows you to select files based on some given criteria, but like Dave says, you could also use `Dir.entries`or `Dir.foreach`

Comment: You can also use [`Dir['*.rb']`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M000630).